# Incorrect auto-indent bash

Tags: indentation

Result of auto-indent in vim (filetype indent on)

```
main() {
    case $1 in  
        --ssh)
        echo "sshing into ${aws_ips[$1]}"
        ssh -i VPN_NODE_1.pem ${aws_ips[$1]}
    ;;  
    --scp)
        echo "scping $2 from ${aws_ips[$1]} to $3"
        scp -r -i VPN_NODE_1.pem ${aws_ips[$1]}:$2 $3  
        ;;  
    esac
```

}

Expected:

```
main()
{
    case $1 in  
        --ssh)
            echo "sshing into ${aws_ips[$1]}"
            ssh -i VPN_NODE_1.pem ${aws_ips[$1]}
            ;;
        --scp)
            echo "scping $2 from ${aws_ips[$1]} to $3"
            scp -r -i VPN_NODE_1.pem ${aws_ips[$1]}:$2 $3
            ;;
    esac
}
```

EDIT: My original post was *incorrect*. I was not using filetype indent on in my .vimrc, I was using it in the vim command prompt

Comment: Welcome on the Vim SE! I think your question is enough comprehensible now to remain open, typically questions with so few sentences are not. I suggest to later use more round sentences in your questions. Good luck on the site!

Comment: What does `:set ft? autoindent? cindent? indentexpr?` show?

Comment: @BLayer filetype=sh
  autoindent
nocindent
  indentexpr=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in comments for some of your settings and you replied with `filetype=sh autoindent nocindent indentexpr=`

If for `indentexpr` you instead had value `GetShIndent()` you'd have the indent scheme you want. You can manually set it up with `:source $VIMRUNTIME/indent/sh.vim`. But that's not what we want. With the proper configuration this should be picked up automatically when you open a shell file.

What's missing in your configuration? My best guess is that you need to add this to your vimrc:

```
filetype indent on
```

Check the current "indent" value (as well as a couple others, "plugin" and "detection" ) with plain `:filetype`. If you see `indent:OFF` then I'm on the right track and you should update your vimrc as suggested.

Comment: In the original post, I had been setting "filetype indent on" through the command prompt in vim... which wasnt working. When I put it in my .vimrc, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Note that it definitely wouldn't work with the command line if you didn't first reload the shell file you're editing (which will re-execute the file type detection logic). But after that it should be good.