# What is necessary to properly indent shell scripts with gg=G?

Tags: indentation

I was editing a small configure script and noticed that vim's indentation of the file was not working properly.  A sample of the original source follows:

```sh
while getopts 'dgSsx' opt; do
    case $opt in
    d) DEBUG=true ;;
    g) USE_GDB=true ;;
        S) USE_GEB=TRUE SMALL=true ;;
        s) SMALL=true ;;
        x) XFT=true ;;
    ?) for line in \
            '-d enable debugging with verbose log output' \
                '-g enable debug symbols' \
                '-s optimize for size' \
                '-x use Xft fonts' \
        '-? show usage'; \
        do echo $line; done ;;
    esac
done
```

After running ***gg=G***, the source looks like this:

```sh
while getopts 'dgSsx' opt; do
case $opt in
d) DEBUG=true ;;
g) USE_GDB=true ;;
S) USE_GEB=TRUE SMALL=true ;;
s) SMALL=true ;;
x) XFT=true ;;
?) for line in \
'-d enable debugging with verbose log output' \
'-g enable debug symbols' \
'-s optimize for size' \
'-x use Xft fonts' \
'-? show usage'; \
do echo $line; done ;;
esac
```

Auto-indent works fine while editing.  What is necessary to get vim's whole-file indentation to work on shell scripts?

Comment: and this is probably duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17667/incorrect-auto-indent-bash?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I did `gg=G` for the buffer with `set ft=sh` I get:

```
while getopts 'dgSsx' opt; do
    case $opt in
        d) DEBUG=true ;;
        g) USE_GDB=true ;;
        S) USE_GEB=TRUE SMALL=true ;;
        s) SMALL=true ;;
        x) XFT=true ;;
        ?) for line in \
            '-d enable debugging with verbose log output' \
            '-g enable debug symbols' \
            '-s optimize for size' \
            '-x use Xft fonts' \
            '-? show usage'; \
        do echo $line; done ;;
    esac
done
```

Which looks ok for me.

When I turned off `filetype indent off` and in a new buffer did the same I got:

```
while getopts 'dgSsx' opt; do
case $opt in
d) DEBUG=true ;;
g) USE_GDB=true ;;
S) USE_GEB=TRUE SMALL=true ;;
s) SMALL=true ;;
x) XFT=true ;;
?) for line in \
        '-d enable debugging with verbose log output' \
        '-g enable debug symbols' \
        '-s optimize for size' \
        '-x use Xft fonts' \
        '-? show usage'; \
        do echo $line; done ;;
esac
done
```

which looks almost like what you have.

- Do you have `filetype indent on` in your vimrc?
- What is your vim version? (I have the latest nightly so it might be something that was fixed)
- What is the output of `verbose set indentexpr?` ?

**PS**

Turn on indent plugins by adding `filetype indent on` to your vimrc.

Comment: I don't have `filetype indent` on in my vimrc.  My vim version is 8.0, so rather old (packaged with Devuan GNU/Linux).  `indentexpr=` is the output, so its empty.  I tried setting ft=sh, but obtained the same results.  I just tried to set filetype indent on in the buffer, but obtained the same results.

Comment: so then add `filetype indent on` to your vimrc... Usually it is `filetype plugin indent on` which turns on filetype and indent plugins

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!